# Query on browsers

Tags: browser

I have used Firefox, Chrome and now Opera. Everytime when I switch browsers, I find that some of the websites don't display or display incorrectly i.e. in terms of box alignments etc.

I have never understood why does this happen. Which property differs in all the browsers that leads to this issue?

Comment: Not a programming question, it is better suited for superuser.com

Comment: How do I move it to superuser.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of those browsers uses a different rendering engine (Firefox -> Gecko; Chrome, Safari -> WebKit; Opera -> Presto), and each rendering engine has different rules about how the markup is displayed and which default attributes are used.

However, if your site is designed properly, these three browsers should have little trouble displaying the correct layout.  It's the Internet Explorer's Trident engine that many people have trouble with.

See the Wikipedia articles on [Web browser engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine) and comparisons amongst them for [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML)) and [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets))